# Rails - 401 Unauthorized when I access action in Production only

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using Ruby On Rails 3.0.9 and everything works fine on Development env. When I switch to Production env, or I upload it to our server, after sign in I'm taken back to the same Login page. When I check the log, I can see the following:

```
Started POST "/users/login" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Oct 03 16:48:13 -0300 2013
  Processing by UserSessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "login"=>"demo_admin"}, "utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+7AEoVXZ9XiagEymVUnOhFHnck4rgDu883E/ySMlCxQ="}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin
Completed 302 Found in 111ms


Started GET "/admin" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Oct 03 16:48:13 -0300 2013
  Processing by Admin::DashboardController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
```

I'm using authorization_rules file in order to manage access, but I've got no problem on Dev env, as I said before.

If I place a breakpoint at the `admin/dashboard#index` action, it won't be executed, as it's not reached. It breaks at httpserver file (I debugged it step by step), but I cannot understand why it works on Dev and not on Prod env.

Please, help.

Thanks,
Brian

**UPDATE**

I forgor to mention that, in my `ApplicationController`, there's a before_filter called `check_plan_features` and the first thing it asks is `unless current_user.blank? #redirects to Admin section`.

I've noticed that after signing in, using Devise, `current_user` has the user's value, but when after redirecting to the admin section, it comes back  to the same filter, and this time, the `current_user` is null. **So, I assume that, somehow, the user's session is destroyed after trying to access Admin section. But, as this only happens on production environment, I'm still wondering what could be.**

Comment: I met a similar problem. just fixed it. not sure if you're facing same problem. my problem was I stupidly added this to user.rb `  before_validation do
    self.roles = ["normal"] if roles.blank?
    if password.blank?
      self.password = DEFAULT_PASSWORD
      self.password_confirmation = DEFAULT_PASSWORD
    end
  end
` ..

Comment: did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: @brian-roisentul how did you solve this? I'm havin the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this exact problem (using rails 4 and devise 3).

The solution was to add a domain declaration to the `config/initializers/session_store.rb` file like this:

```
YourAppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_your_session', domain: {
  production: 'production_domain',
  development: 'development_domain'
}.fetch(Rails.env.to_sym, :all)
```

Though it is important that this was changed initially due to adding sub-domains to the application.

Comment: this did not work for me, and also, I get ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in development, on localhost.