# Rails app returning 401 Unauthorized while logging in only in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

I can't login in my app that is deployed on Heroku, so that one is in `production`. On my local machine the one that runs the `development` it does work without a problem. Both the databases are exactly the same as they are dump copies of each other.

I verified the user does exist in the remote database and the password is given in correctly, both local and remote version are from the same branch and are synced.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24885909/3845362) solution, but my `config/initializers/session_store.rb` looks like this:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.
FilteredWeb::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_filtered-web_session', domain: :all
```

Someone also suggested changing the encryption key in [config/initializers/devise.rb](http://pastebin.com/0ULya5d0) but I don't see where to do this and neither do I understand the logic behind it.

**Versions**

```
devise (2.2.3)
rails (3.2.13)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact error... removing the `domain: :all` fixed it for me. 
See [a similar issue on github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2734)